# how to get category name in wordpress by post id sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

how to get category name in wordpress by post id sql query ??
i need the sql query

Comment: Have you tried something or should we do it for you? Show us your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below Query:

```
select t.name from wp_terms t, wp_term_taxonomy tt, wp_term_relationships tr
where t.term_id=tt.term_id AND tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id and tr.object_id=YOUR_POST_ID
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get categories direct via sql query as

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM `wp_terms` t
JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` tt ON(t.`term_id` = tt.`term_id`)
JOIN `wp_term_relationships` ttr ON(ttr.`term_taxonomy_id` = tt.`term_taxonomy_id`)
WHERE tt.`taxonomy` = 'category'
AND ttr.`object_id` = @postid
```

In above query you need to provide taxonomy name in case if you are using any custom post type categories